# How to make a description appear when clicking on the graph points iOS

Tags: ios, graph, popup, core-plot

Does anybody have an idea about placing the values of the coordinates of the graph diagonally?

EDIT: I succeeded displaying the values of the oX-axis diagonally. Maybe it can help someone:

```
   label.rotation = M_PI/4;
```

The other question would be if somebody can give me some links or tutorials on how to make a description appear near the point of the scatter plot, that I click on.

This is my code for the scatter plots, that I draw on the graph:

```
   -(void)initPlot {
[self configureHost];
[self configureGraph];
[self configurePlots];
[self configureAxes];
 }

-(void)configureHost {

self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40 , 480, 280)];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];

}

-(void)configureGraph {

graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
// 2 - Set graph title
NSString *title = @"Valori";
graph.title = title;
// 3 - Create and set text style
CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
// 4 - Set padding for plot area
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:30.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];
// 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

}

-(void)configurePlots {

// 1 - Get graph and plot space
graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
// 2 - Create the three plots

aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
[graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];


msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
msftPlot.dataSource = self;
msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
[graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
// 3 - Set up plot space

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:aaplPlot, msftPlot, nil];
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:array];

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
// 4 - Create styles and symbols
CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;


CPTMutableLineStyle *msftLineStyle = [msftPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
msftLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
msftLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
msftPlot.dataLineStyle = msftLineStyle;
CPTMutableLineStyle *msftSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
msftSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
CPTPlotSymbol *msftSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
msftSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:msftColor];
msftSymbol.lineStyle = msftSymbolLineStyle;
msftSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
msftPlot.plotSymbol = msftSymbol;

}

-(void)configureAxes {

// 1 - Create styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
// 2 - Get axis set
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
// 3 - Configure x-axis
CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.title = @"Ziua Lunii";
x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
NSInteger i = 0;
for (NSString *date in [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth]) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    CGFloat location = i++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}
x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
// 4 - Configure y-axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.title = @"Pret";
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = -50.0f;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.labelOffset = 23.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
NSInteger majorIncrement = 100;
NSInteger minorIncrement = 50;
CGFloat yMax = 1300.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
    NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
    if (mod == 0) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
        NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
        label.tickLocation = location;
        label.offset = - y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
        if (label) {
            [yLabels addObject:label];
        }
        [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
    } else {
        [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
    }
}
y.axisLabels = yLabels;
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` for this purpose, as demonstrated in the [examples of Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CPTTestApp/Source/Controller.m)

Comment: Several of the Core Plot example apps show how to do this including three of the scatter plots in the *Plot Gallery* app.